# In Azure Blob Storage should I group user data using containers or blob names?

Tags: azure

I am going to use the Azure Blob Storage on my backend to store user data (some JSON files but it does not matter).

Should I create a container per user or should I use a single container and put all data there using hierarchical blob names like "user-id/blob-name"?

Comment: How does your user id look like? Is it a GUID?

Comment: @GauravMantri Yes, it is a unique hex string (a MongoDB ObjectId actually).

Comment: Thanks. Can you share an example?

Comment: a240b1a22171499eac9f9e23